# Why is my code returning the else statement and undefined and not the totalBasketballScore?

Tags: javascript

I really thought I had this code correct. I am trying to calculate basketball score with free throws, 2 pointers and 3 pointers. The output when I console.log the totalBasketballScore ends up being 'All entries must be numbers' and undefined. What do I need to change so I get the score when I put the 3 values in the parameters?

```js
function totalBasketballScore(numberFreeThrows, numberMidRange, numberThreePointers) {
  const freeThrows = 1;
  const midRange = 2;
  const threePointers = 3;

  if (typeof numberFreeThrows === 'number' && numberMidRange === 'number' && numberThreePointers === 'number') {
    let totalFreeThrows = freeThrows * numberFreeThrows;
    let totalMidRange = midRange * numberMidRange;
    let totalThreePointers = threePointers * numberThreePointers;
    let gameTotal = totalFreeThrows + totalMidRange + totalThreePointers;
    return gameTotal;

  } else {
    console.log('All Entries Must Be a Number');
  }
}
console.log(totalBasketballScore(1, 2, 4));
```

Comment: You have to use `typeof` with each check: `typeof numberFreeThrows === 'number' && typeof numberMidRange === 'number' && typeof numberThreePointers === 'number'`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that can be used is isNaN(). isNaN can be used to check if the value is Not a Number. If isNaN() returns false, the value is a number.

```
function totalBasketballScore(numberFreeThrows, numberMidRange, numberThreePointers) {
const freeThrows = 1;
  const midRange = 2;
  const threePointers = 3;

  if(isNaN(numberFreeThrows)=== false && isNaN(numberMidRange)=== false && isNaN(numberThreePointers)=== false) {
    let totalFreeThrows = freeThrows * numberFreeThrows;
    let totalMidRange = midRange * numberMidRange;
    let totalThreePointers = threePointers * numberThreePointers;
    let gameTotal = totalFreeThrows + totalMidRange + totalThreePointers;
    return gameTotal;

  } else {
    console.log('All Entries Must Be a Number');
  }
}
console.log(totalBasketballScore(1, 2, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `typeof` per each parameter, like this:

```js
if(typeof numberFreeThrows === 'number' && typeof numberMidRange === 'number' && typeof numberThreePointers === 'number'){

} else {

}
```